# override LinkMovementMethod textview android

Tags: android, textview, linkmovementmethod

I need to override default LinkMovementMethod. But it's calling the default LinkMovementMethod. Here is the code:

```
class MovementCheck extends LinkMovementMethod {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, 
        Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event ) {
        try {
            Log.d("sg", "check check check");
            return super.onTouchEvent( widget, buffer, event ) ;
        } catch( ActivityNotFoundException ex ) {
            Log.d("sg", "Error");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

...

```
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(rules.getObjects().get(0).getDescription());
rulesBody.setText(spanned);
rulesBody.setMovementMethod(MovementCheck.getInstance());
```

## Solution

Figured out the correct implementation.. Could be useful:

```
class MovementCheck extends LinkMovementMethod {

    private static MovementCheck sInstance;

    public static MovementCheck getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null)
            sInstance = new MovementCheck();
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, 
        Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event ) {
        try {
            return super.onTouchEvent( widget, buffer, event ) ;
        } catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            CrashLytics.logException(ex);
            new UtilitySingleton().ShowToast("Link Broken...!!");
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

I was missing the `setInstance` method which was creating a new instance of LinkMovementMethod.

Comment: hmmmm...  errr...  and?

Comment: It was using the default implementation of linkmovement method.But figured out the problem.Will edit the post.